# ASP.net MVC2 validation for my Dropdown list boxes?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Can anyone give me a nice link to Implement ASP.NET MVC2 validation for my dropdownlist in my view?

My Dropdownlist in my view is something like this:

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedStudent, 
                         new SelectList(Model.StudentIDs, "ID", "Name"),
                         "Please select..", 
                         new { id="Student", style = "width:190px;" })%>
```

and my validation message is:

```
  <%:Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedStudent) %>
```

in my Model I have this validation:

```
[DisplayName("Student")]
[Required(ErrorMessage="Please Select StudentID.")]
public int Student{ get; set; }
```

But somehow it's not validating and I am not seeing validation message in my view.

Something causing problem with "Please select"? or please correct me if I am wrong..

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your view, you'll want to put something like this:

```
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DropDownListReference) %>
```

In your model, something like this

```
public class Whatever
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a Whatever!")]
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public int DropDownListReference { get; set; }
}
```

This is assuming that you just want to validate that they've selected something.

Comment: Thanks TreFrog, Do I need to use EnableClientValidation in my view?

Comment: If you want the validation to happen via Javascript, yeah. But this way will just render the page if they type in something wrong.

Comment: Yes I validated with Javascript its working fine for me.. but I want to try with MVC2 validation.. why its behaving like this.. if my Dropdown list box has Please select its throwing '' value not null value.. is this causing problem?

Comment: I changed my example above to better fit what you're talking about. Make sure that the "Please select" option has a value of 0.

Comment: but now I am getting Please select value is '' allways.. how to give the Value as 0 in my dropdownlistfor code?

Comment: Are you saying that you're getting the validation message always, no matter what you put in? What are some sample values of your student IDs?

Comment: var RT = $("#RType").val();
                if (BT == '') {
                    alert("Please Select StudentID!");
                    return false;
                }

Comment: Try this one. I think this is what you want 100%.

Comment: Try changing the type to string.